# Trying to get property 'label' of non-object

Tags: laravel, php7, route, app, laravel-8

Здраствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста решить ошибку.

Скачал Систему электронной коммерций **FleetCart** Создал товар в админ панели, перехожу на сайт для покупки, нажимаю купить выводит ошибку **Trying to get property 'label' of non-object**

**Вот строка полного лога**

```
[2021-09-25 08:22:02] production.ERROR: Trying to get property 'label' of non-object {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'label' of non-object at D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Cart\\Cart.php:187)
```

**Перехожу к файлу на строку 187**

```
182    public function addShippingMethod($shippingMethod)
183    {
184        $this->removeShippingMethod();
185
186        $this->condition(new CartCondition([
187            'name' => $shippingMethod->label,
188            'type' => 'shipping_method',
189            'target' => 'total',
190           'value' => "+{$shippingMethod->cost->amount()}",
191            'order' => 1,
192            'attributes' => [
193                'shipping_method' => $shippingMethod,
194            ],
195        ]));
196
197        $this->refreshFreeShippingCoupon();
198
199        return $this->shippingMethod();
200    }
```

Вот полный лог

```
[2021-09-25 08:22:02] production.ERROR: Trying to get property 'label' of non-object {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'label' of non-object at D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Cart\\Cart.php:187)
[stacktrace]
#0 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Cart\\Cart.php(187): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade.php(261): Modules\\Cart\\Cart->addShippingMethod()
#2 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Checkout\\Services\\OrderService.php(90): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic()
#3 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Checkout\\Services\\OrderService.php(21): Modules\\Checkout\\Services\\OrderService->addShippingMethodToCart()
#4 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Checkout\\Http\\Controllers\\CheckoutController.php(80): Modules\\Checkout\\Services\\OrderService->create()
#5 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): Modules\\Checkout\\Http\\Controllers\\CheckoutController->store()
#6 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#7 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#8 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#9 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#10 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#11 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Cart\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckCouponUsageLimit.php(25): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#12 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Modules\\Cart\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckCouponUsageLimit->handle()
#13 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Cart\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckCartStock.php(33): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#14 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Modules\\Cart\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckCartStock->handle()
#15 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\Modules\\Cart\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfCartIsEmpty.php(24): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Modules\\Cart\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfCartIsEmpty->handle()
#17 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#18 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#19 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#21 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#23 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#25 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\mcamara\\laravel-localization\\src\\Mcamara\\LaravelLocalization\\Middleware\\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter.php(45): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#26 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Mcamara\\LaravelLocalization\\Middleware\\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter->handle()
#27 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\mcamara\\laravel-localization\\src\\Mcamara\\LaravelLocalization\\Middleware\\LocaleSessionRedirect.php(64): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#28 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Mcamara\\LaravelLocalization\\Middleware\\LocaleSessionRedirect->handle()
#29 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\mcamara\\laravel-localization\\src\\Mcamara\\LaravelLocalization\\Middleware\\LaravelLocalizationRoutes.php(30): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#30 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Mcamara\\LaravelLocalization\\Middleware\\LaravelLocalizationRoutes->handle()
#31 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#32 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#33 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#34 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#35 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#36 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#37 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#38 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\beyondcode\\laravel-query-detector\\src\\QueryDetectorMiddleware.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#39 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): BeyondCode\\QueryDetector\\QueryDetectorMiddleware->handle()
#40 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\barryvdh\\laravel-debugbar\\src\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar.php(60): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#41 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle()
#42 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\RunUpdater.php(23): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): FleetCart\\Http\\Middleware\\RunUpdater->handle()
#44 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectToInstallerIfNotInstalled.php(22): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#45 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): FleetCart\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectToInstallerIfNotInstalled->handle()
#46 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#47 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#48 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#49 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#50 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#51 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#52 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#53 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#54 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#55 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#56 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#57 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#58 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#59 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#60 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): FleetCart\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
#61 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#62 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#63 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#64 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#65 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#66 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#67 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#68 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#69 D:\\OpenServer\\domains\\mysite\\public\\index.php(70): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#70 {main}
"}
```

Comment: `$shippingMethod` у вас null или false или массив. В общем не объект к атрибутам которого можно обратиться через `->`

Comment: ArchDemon Привет. Подскажи пожалуйста как можно сделать label объектом?

Comment: для начала нужно понять чем он является сейчас

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо за помощь. Ты дал подсказку я от нее оттолкнулся и решил  эту проблему. Спасибо еще раз.